# Checking database for form input, and then responding with some specific content

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a asp.net mvc application where I have a form in one of my views.
From that for, the user needs to be able to  type in the name of another user, and if that name exists in my database, I display a specific output, and if not another.
So I want something along the lines of:

```
    <form action="Checkifuserexists">
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Add a friend"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>        
    @if (resultOffunction == True)
    {
        <p> succes, this user exists </p>
    }
    else
    {
        <p> THis user does not exist </p>
    }
```

So, I'm aware that since this is gonna be clientside and my c# is serverside, I'm gonna have to call a function which will redirect me back to my view again.

My question is though, how do I best pass along the information about the query being a succes or not along?

My first thought was to set a cookie, return to the same view, and then do something like this:

```
        if (Request.Cookies["response"] == "true")
        {
             <p> succes, this user exists </p>
        } else 
        {
            <p> THis user does not exist </p>
        }
```

This doesnt seem best practice though, and I could end up having a hundred cookies just to keep track of the state of the site.

I could also take a query string, which might be a bit better, or somehow put the information into the model I return anyway. Both of these solutions seem a little strange though.

What would be the best way of doing this?

**EDIT**

I have now gotten the tip of using some js to call some c# backend function. I then found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pdj4YOfWH00), and tried following it.

I now have this function in my homecointroller which is the one I want to call (for now it just returns a string):

```
[JSInvokable]
public string addFriend()
{
    System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal currrentUser = this.User;
    return "Hi there";
}
```

I have this javascript:

```
              function focusonElement(element){
                  element.focus();
             }
             function setElementTextById(id, text) {
                  document.getElementById(id).innerText = text
                  }
                  
              function addFriend() {
                  Dotnet.invokeMethodAsync('mongoExample' ,'addFriend')
                    .then(result => {
                        setElementTextById('searchspan', result);
                    });
                  }
```

(The name of my project is "monoExample")

And I have this html:

```
    <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="addFriend()"> get friend</button>

        <p id ='searchNotification'> The user <span id='searchspan'></span> </p>
```

When I click the button, I can tell that the function gets called, but my backend function never does. Why could this be?

I also tried having the function in  myt razor file:

```
@{
 [JSInvokable]
 static string DoTHis()
{
    return "RETURNING THISs";
}
    

}
```

This has the same effect.
I guess the issue is that javascript cannot resolve `invokeMethodAsync`. But do I need to inmport something to make it work? or do I need to use blazor?

Comment: This seems to be an ideal situation for some javascript code and ajax call to a server side method

Comment: prob the best option

Comment: Exactly, you don't need to leave the page and then return to it. Just call the server side method and apply your logic directly on the page with JavaScript or JQuery. There are many examples how to do it, just be sure to look at the examples for your client and server context (Ie Razor Pages? pure MVC with just controllers and views?. Sometime this is so confusing)

Comment: I can find tutorials for blazor, but i'm not a 100 percent certain that thta might work for me. Do you know of any articles/tutorials/code snippets that I could take a look at?

Comment: I added a small edit with me trying to implement this

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your request but for sure no need for cookies,
if you have data before response return it with model and check in view:

```
if (Model.data == "true")
        {
             <p> succes, this user exists </p>
        }
```

if not use ajax call to check and use jquery to show result

Comment: yeah, packing the response into the could be an option. But I already have a model taht I am returning, anmd it feels clunky to keep packing more and more things into that model